# Proxy server with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, proxy

We have a project that sends program logs to the logging system (a separate application). Sending takes place via Kafka. It is necessary to conduct testing, according to the scenario of which the connection between applications is broken and restored. Is it possible to implement this by creating a proxy server? Kafka confuses me...

We haven't had any attempts yet

Comment: There's a project on Github literally named `kafka-proxy`. Have you tried it? Otherwise, regular unit/integration tests can be written for Kafka clients, and don't require proxying network traffic